# What's Unity's Transform equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine

In Unity, it's very easy to rotate an object or relating a parent with a child using `Transform` class and its methods.

Is there a library that provides `Transform` class that store position, rotation, and scale in Python?

Comment: You mean something like https://pypi.org/project/transformations/ ?

Comment: Yes something like that